Get user data after authentication in flutter using Firebase Auth and Bloc
I am building a flutter app and using Bloc and Firebase,
i am trying to access user data after signing in through get user function but i couldn't do it,
here is my user repository implementation:
class FirebaseUserRepo implements UserRepository {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth;
  final userCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
  static MyUser myUserObject = MyUser.empty;

  FirebaseUserRepo({FirebaseAuth? firebaseAuth})
      : _firebaseAuth = firebaseAuth ?? FirebaseAuth.instance;
  @override
  // TODO: implement user
  Stream<User?> get user {
    return _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().map((firebaseUser) {
      return firebaseUser;
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<void> signIn(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
          getUser();
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<MyUser> signUp(MyUser myUser, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential user = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: myUser.email, password: password);

      myUser = myUser.CopyWith(
        userId: user.user?.uid,
      );

      return myUser;
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> setUserData(MyUser myUser) async {
    try {
      await userCollection
          .doc(myUser.userId)
          .set(myUser.toEntity().toDocument());
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
      rethrow;
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> signOut() async {
    await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }

   getUser() async {
    try {
      final User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  final uid = user?.uid;
  myUserObject = await userCollection.doc(uid).get().then(
        (value) => MyUser.fromEntity(UserEntity.fromDocument(value.data())));
      return userCollection.doc(uid).get().then(
        (value) => MyUser.fromEntity(UserEntity.fromDocument(value.data())));
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
      rethrow;
    }
  }
}

my Authentication bloc:
class AuthenticationBloc extends Bloc<AuthenticationEvent, AuthenticationState> {
  final UserRepository userRepository;
  late final StreamSubscription<User?> _streamSubscription; 
  AuthenticationBloc({required this.userRepository}) :
   super(const AuthenticationState.unknown()) {
    _streamSubscription = userRepository.user.listen((user) {
      add(AuthenticationUserChanged(user: user));
    });
  
    on<AuthenticationUserChanged>((event, emit) {
      if(event.user != null){
        emit(AuthenticationState.authenticated(event.user!));
      }else{
        emit(AuthenticationState.unauthenticated());

      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    _streamSubscription.cancel(); 
    return super.close();
  }
}

and that's my sign in bloc:
class SignInBloc extends Bloc<SignInEvent, SignInState> {
  UserRepository _userRepository;
  SignInBloc({required UserRepository userRepository}) :_userRepository = userRepository, super(SignInInitial()) {
    
    
    on<SignInRequired>((event, emit) async {
      emit(SignInProcess());
      try {
        await _userRepository.signIn(event.email, event.Password);
        emit(SignInSuccess());
      }on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        emit(SignInFailure(message: e.toString()));
      }catch(e){
        emit(SignInFailure(message: e.toString()));
      }      
    });


  on<SignOutEvent>((event,emit) async{
    await _userRepository.signOut();
  });
  }


}


Here is how i used these classes in the front-end:
my app view:

class MyAppView extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyAppView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    MyUser myUser = MyUser.empty;
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(
            background: Colors.white,
            onBackground: Colors.black,
            primary: Color(0xFF0E39C6),
            onPrimary: Colors.black,
            secondary: Color(0xFF0DA6C2),
            onSecondary: Colors.white,
            tertiary: Color(0xFFFF8D6C),
            error: Colors.red,
            outline: Color(0xFF424242)),
      ),
      title: 'Kyysh',
      home: BlocBuilder<AuthenticationBloc, AuthenticationState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
        if (state.status == AuthenticationStatus.authenticated) {
          return BlocProvider<SignInBloc>(
            create: (context) {
              return SignInBloc(
                  userRepository:
                      context.read<AuthenticationBloc>().userRepository);
            },
            child: BlocProvider<MyUserBloc>(
              create: (context) {
                return MyUserBloc(
                    context.read<AuthenticationBloc>().userRepository);
              },
              child: BlocBuilder<MyUserBloc, MyUserState>(
                  builder: (context, state) {
                if (state is MyUserSuccess) {
                  return HomeScreen(myUser: state.myUser);
                } else {
                  return WelcomeScreen();
                }
              }),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return const WelcomeScreen();
        }
      }),
    );
  }
}

i want to send MyUser object to the home screen to be able to access the data but it keeps showing the welcome screen - which contains the sign in screen-
thanks in advance

Welcome to SO. That's a LOT of code for us to parse through so best practice is to narrow down where the trouble is so we can focus on that. A good first step is to do some basic troubleshooting by adding a breakpoint and stepping through the code line by line, inspecting the vars and code execution until you spot something unexpected. Then update your question indicating where the code goes wrong.
